# Ensure one of the RadioButton in a RadioGroup is selected in Android

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

If I have the following radiogroup:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="6" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbBrides"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Bridge" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/gbTunnel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tunnel" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbHighway"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Highway" />
</RadioGroup>
```

And I want to do the following check:

```
If (rgType is selected) {
system.out.println("ok");
}
if (rgType is void/null/not selected) {
system.out.println("choose at least one selection");
}
```

Can I use `isChecked()` which is used for individual radio buttons, like the following?

```
if (rgType.isChecked()) {

}
else {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getCheckedRadioButtonId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29) and see if one of your `RadioButtons` is checked. I'm not exactly sure what it returns if none are but probably either `null` or more likely `-1`. Either way, run that and see what it returns.

I believe it does return -1 if nothing checked so try

```
  if (rgType == -1)
  {
      system.out.println("choose at least one selection");        
  }
  else
  {
       system.out.println("ok");  
  }
```

[RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29)

Comment: Would I be able to get an indexOf?

Comment: indexOf what? If they are in an array then I suppose you could. Exactly what do you want? Look at the link I posted, it gives you available functions.